# How to solve inequality equations of kappa modifiers using FindInstance command?

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

Here, ub are signal strength values while ube is error value. similarly, other values. THbb and other are higgs decay width values. these values are required values for making inequalities mentioned below. This code is for finding kappa parameter values kg,kb,kw,ktau,kgma,kz,kmu,kh values with error values (between 0 to 2 range).

```
ube = 0.15
uw = 1.08
uwe = 0.18
uz = 1.19
uze = 0.12
ugma = 1.1
ugmae = 0.15
umu = 0.6
umue = 0.8
utau = 1.11
utaue = 0.17
Thbb = 2379 
Thtautau = 256
Thmumu = 0.89
ThWW = 883
ThZZ = 108
Thgmagma = 9.3

inequalities = {ub - ube <= (Subscript[k, g]^2*Subscript[k, b]^2)/
     Subscript[k, h]^2 <= ub + ube,
   utau - utaue <= (Subscript[k, g]^2*kSubscript[k, tau]^2)/
     Subscript[k, h]^2 <= utau + utaue,
   uw - uwe <= (Subscript[k, g]^2*Subscript[k, w]^2)/
     Subscript[k, h]^2 <= uw + uwe,
   uz - uze <= (Subscript[k, g]^2*Subscript[k, z]^2)/
     Subscript[k, h]^2 <= uz + uze,
   ugma - ugmae <= (Subscript[k, g]^2*Subscript[k, gma]^2)/
     Subscript[k, h]^2 <= ugma + ugmae,
   umu - umue <= (Subscript[k, g]^2*Subscript[k, mu]^2)/
     Subscript[k, h]^2 <= umu + umue,
   Subscript[k, 
      h]^2 == (THbb*Subscript[k, g]^2 + Thtautau*Subscript[k, tau]^2 +
        Thmumu*Subscript[k, mu]^2 + ThWW*Subscript[k, w]^2 + 
       ThZZ*Subscript[k, z]^2 + Thgmagma*Subscript[k, gma]^2)/6.1 };

solution = 
 Solve[inequalities, {Subscript[k, g], Subscript[k, b], 
   Subscript[k, w], Subscript[k, gma], Subscript[k, z], 
   Subscript[k, mu], Subscript[k, tau]}]

FindInstance[
 inequalities && 
  Between[{Subscript[k, g], Subscript[k, b], Subscript[k, w], 
    Subscript[k, gma], Subscript[k, z], Subscript[k, mu], 
    Subscript[k, tau]}, {0, 2}] , {Subscript[k, g], Subscript[k, b], 
  Subscript[k, w], Subscript[k, gma], Subscript[k, z], 
  Subscript[k, mu], Subscript[k, tau], Subscript[k, h]}, Reals ]
```

How to solve

1. Set and in inequality and Kh^2 is protected.
2. FindInstance, positive machine-sized integer at position 4 in FindInstance.

**Please help me to solve this higgs kappa modifier coupling equations (inequality equations).**

Comment: What is `THbb`?  What is `kSubscript[k, tau]`?